# Drop columns in series/dataframe MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I am not sure if i have a dataframe or a series. After I get my data into the df or series, I would like to drop those first two columns and it will not work.

```
csv_data1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", delimiter=",") 
csv_data1["Date"] = csv_data1["Date"].astype("datetime64")

csv_data2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", delimiter=",")
csv_data2["Date"] = csv_data2["Date"].astype("datetime64")

csv_data1.set_index(["Vendor ID", "PO #", "Item ID"], drop=False, inplace=True)
csv_data2.set_index(["Vendor ID", "PO #", "Item ID"], drop=False, inplace=True)

difference = ((csv_data1["Date"] - csv_data2["Date"]).dt.days / 7).abs()
```

Here is my DF/Series:

```
Vendor ID  PO #      Item ID  
TRLIM      20210339  X18TE1779    17.714286
                     X18TE1779    17.714286
                     X18TE1779    17.714286
                     X18TE1779    17.714286
                     X18TE1780    17.714286
                                    ...
TRSSP      NaN       X13SL0458          NaN
                     X15TE0334          NaN
                     X17TR1674          NaN
                     X32TR2654          NaN
                     X50TE7420          NaN
```

I would like to drop the `Vendor ID` and the `PO #` index/column
I have tried this:

```
difference.drop(labels=['Vendor ID', 'PO #'], axis = 1)
```

Which gives me:

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series
```

As well as this:

```
difference.dropna(inplace = True)
```

So how could I do this? If it is a series, is there a way to convert it to a DF? I have tried `difference.to_frame()`, but I am not sure how to check.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get rid of multiindex, not columns. What's the desired result?

Comment: I would like to drop the first two indexes `[0,1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
out = difference.droplevel(['Vendor ID', 'PO #'])
```

output:

```
Item ID
X18TE1779    17.714286
X18TE1779    17.714286
X18TE1779    17.714286
X18TE1779    17.714286
X18TE1780    17.714286
X13SL0458          NaN
X15TE0334          NaN
X17TR1674          NaN
X32TR2654          NaN
X50TE7420          NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

`difference.reset_index(drop=True)` should work since you have a created an index...

`difference.drop()` is used for columns and rows, since you have created an index use the function `difference.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: So how would it drop the first two columns or index `{0,1}` as that is what I would like to do because I do not know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: have you tried doing difference.drop(columns = ['Vendor ID', 'PO #']) instead of labels as a parameter?

Comment: Yes and the two columns are still there and I am not 100% sure why, I was thinking maybe make a new Df with just the data I need unless theres a way to drop these